# Bootstrap modal not hiding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap modal to show some info to a user that access a site, so I need it to show right when this user has access to that site. Used a similar modal in another page that showed after clicking a button and I had no problems with it, but now, since I'm showing the modal right when the page loads, I can't hide it after pressing the button. Any help would be very much appreciated. Also, I don't think it matters that much, but I'm using Yii.

Here's the code:

```
<div id='modalConfirm' class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">Reservation Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" align="center">
        <p>This is your confirmation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="accButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#modalConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
 $(function(){
     $('#accButton').click(function(){
          $('#modalConfirm').modal('hide');
      });
  });
```

Comment: What is there in your console, when you click close button

Comment: @zan this is embarrassing, but I don't actually know how to show the console value when clicking the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're showing it as part of the HTML, you may want to hide it by just using plain-ol-jQuery.

```
$("#modalConfirm").hide();
```

Alternatively, you could try using Javascript to hide it at page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modalConfirm").modal("show");
});
```

Using this solution, you use the modal as it was originally intended and may have better results when calling the modal hide method.

Either way, double check that your bootstrap Javascript files are being properly included and that the modal function actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried the first solution you propose but it doesn't work, nothing still happens. As for the second solution, I need the user to be able to see the modal when the page loads, and to close it whenever they want by clicking the Accept button, so I'm not actually sure this would work. Edit: Ok, I made a small mistake implementing your second answer, after fixing it the modal could be closed, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! I'm a little puzzled to as why the first solution didn't work for you though, is it possible you have something in your CSS that may be interfering?

Comment: I'm not sure, since the only CSS code I've implemented yet is what I posted. Just in case, the way to make the second solution work was to set the class to "model hide" and replacing the original CSS with the one provided in Julian's second answer. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

### Try close class of modal

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">   <span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button> 
<h4 class="modal-title">Clear Monthly Data.</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and it also works, thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked as below. Please try for your scenario as well.

```
this.$hide();
```